# Java shutdown hooks with ExecutorService

Tags: java, shutdown, executorservice

I'm running into a problem when shutting down my application that the ExecutorService has been terminated...What's a good way to deal with this?

```
public class TradingLock {

    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private List<TradingHaltedListener> listeners=new ArrayList<>();
    public TradingLock(ExecutorService executorService) {
        super();
        this.executorService = executorService;
    }

    public void haltTrading(){
        for (final TradingHaltedListener listener: listeners){
            executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    listener.onTradingHalted();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public synchronized void addTradingHaltedListener(TradingHaltedListener listener){
        this.listeners.add(listener);
    }
}
```

Shutdown hook from main class:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            tradingLock.haltTrading();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I make a class that extends Thread and use that inside the `addShutdownHook` function that it runs with no problems.

```
 public class ShutdownHandler extends Thread {
      public void run(){
           // do all the work to clean up before shutting down
      }
 }
```

and then just add it in the main class

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new ShutdownHandler());
```

**EDIT**

After reading a little more about the `ExecutorService`, it could be that this is receiving a `shutdown` or `shutdownNow` when the application starts to exit. The `addShutdownHook` is fired when the application begins its shutdown sequence. So it is possible that the `ExecutorService` is shutdown before your Shutdown hook is started.